# Reflection and thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I use spring boot and thymeleaf. I have many entity and I need to create crud ui. All ui will be similar Is it possible to use reflection to reduce ui to generate?

I would like to loop on the fields and get value in the thymeleaf template

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish?  (Perhaps a code example?)

Comment: like i said, i have around 60 entity. instead of writing fragment for every of them, i would like to write one and loop on field of the entity

Comment: Wouldn't one template suffice?  Loop through each field on the server-side and add them to your model.  Or are you trying to generate the HTML dynamically? If so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these days I have been working on an issue very similar to yours.

I have discovered that Thymeleaf has this thing called [preprocessing](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing) which allows you to have nested expression, so something like this works:

```html
<p th:text="${__${'myObj.myField'}__}"></p>
```

In this situation, the expression `__${'myObj.myField'}__` is evaluated first: after this preprocessing, the expression that will be evaluated by the `<p>` tag will become:

```html
<p th:text="${myObj.myField}"></p>
```

Which is the desidered result. Note that, in the preprocessed expression, we are passing the field as a string: therefore, it should be totally possible to create a fragments with a `th:each` in it which accepts a list of strings in which each string is a field. This list could either be injected directly in the model through Java or could be [statically declared](http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/03/03/thymeleaf-create-a-list-of-elements-statically/) in the Thymeleaf's markup. An example of such fragment could be:

```html
<div th:fragment = "show-details">
    <tr th:each = "field : ${fieldsToPrint}">
        <td th:text = "${__${myObj + '.' + field}__}"></td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Which could, for example, be used like this:

```html
<div th:replace = "myfragments :: show-details(fieldsToPrint = ${ {'name', 'surname'} }, myObj = ${objFromModel})"></div>
```

The list of fields could either be generate manually or through Java reflection.

This procedure still involves some work, but way less than creating by hand all the views, especially if you can show all the entities with the same `show-details` fragments. I have not got around to it yet, but it should be possible to use a similar pattern also for editing such entities.

Comment: +1 fantastic answer for those who are unfamiliar with Thymeleaf. Code samples are especially appreciated.